# Is it wrong to say “I'd call you”?

Tags: grammaticality

A couple of days ago, I used:

> I'd call you

At the end of my conversation, and my teacher noticed that's wrong! Is it technically wrong? I meant to say that I would call you (if I need your help)

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is right.

You meant to say: **I'll call you** (or **I will call you**)
which may inform the person you are speaking to of your intention or may just be a way of ending the conversation.

To say: **I would call you** implies that you mean **if you needed to**.
It is not the correct way to end a conversation unless it follows something that has been said, such as:

> Your friend: **Our house is quite difficult to find, so if you have a problem....**
> You:         **(Then) I would call you.**

Comment: Yeah, that's it, but what if I meant to say this
I would call you. [I would call you, rather than text you.] Or [I would call you, rather than someone else.] 
I reckon that I must say the rest of the sentence, otherwise it'll be wrong.

Comment: @MohammadArab It is as you say/